# Unable to find an entry point named xfeatures2d_SIFT_create

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying to write to use library openCVSharp3 with .NET 4.5 and VS2015 which should be just wrapper for OpenCV 3.0 but so far with no success. I wrote really simple Console application in C# just with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var sift = SIFT.Create(100);
}
```

But i get this exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in OpenCvSharp.dll
Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'xfeatures2d_SIFT_create' in DLL 'OpenCvSharpExtern'.

i looked into code of openCVSharp and this method actually exist but is in block marked with

```
#ifdef ENABLED_CONTRIB
```

Is there a way how to determine if this was enabled or not in current nuget package.

I dont know how should i proceed with debugging this exception since i never wrote any kind of wrapper for c++ library.
Also i dont know if my VS2015 with VC14 compiler does not mind this code.

**Edit :**
Sample project from openCVSharp for sift algorithm throw the same exception... my guess is that its disabled in this version of nuget package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out, in OpenCV 3.0 SIFT and SURF have moved to the external contrib library and are currently not supported in OpenCvSharp v3.0.  You can find more details on this here https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/146 as well as suggestions.

Comment: Yeah thanks... i ll mark this as an answer and maybe even consider contributing to OpenCVSharp to add support for some contrib packages..